# Gtk-WARNING: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "wimp"

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I developed an Gtk Application that works on Windows.
I use pyInstaller to build one exe file.
Everything would be OK if not for the theme that not loads.

**So, I have my spec file:**

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

directory = 'C:\\my_project'

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=[directory],
             hiddenimports=None,
             hookspath=None)


more_datas = []
more_binaries = []

more_datas.append(('gtkrc', os.path.join(directory, 'gtkrc'), 'DATA'))
more_binaries.append(('libwimp.dll', os.path.join(directory, 'libwimp.dll'), 'BINARY'))

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries + more_binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas + more_datas,
          name='main.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True)
```

In the DATA section, I include the gtkrc file And in BINARIES section, I include the libwimp.dll. Both files are in my application directory.

**In my project python code, I have:**

```
def resource_path(relative):
    directory = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.getcwd())
    return os.path.join(directory, relative)


theme = resource_path("gtkrc")
gtk.rc_set_default_files([theme])
gtk.rc_reparse_all_for_settings(gtk.settings_get_default(), True)
gtk.rc_reset_styles(gtk.settings_get_for_screen(window.get_screen()))
```

When I run application, a temporary directory is created ("_MEIXXXXXX") and the two files are included there.

**But the console shows the message:**

> Gtk-WARNING: Unable to locate theme engine in  module_path: "wimp"

And the theme not load.
This Warning appears after this code bellow is called:

```
gtk.rc_reparse_all_for_settings(gtk.settings_get_default(), True)
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found where I was going wrong.

The problem was that I copied the theme to the local directory of my application. The libwimp.dll file must be created within a specific directory to work in the temporary folder.

This tip helped me solve:

[Add hooks for PyGTK themes](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/14)